# Spring RestTemplate, how to create extract only one inner node from json response

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I'm using SpringRest template to convert json response to a custom object, but i need to convert only a part of the response. Here is my attempt:

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 Response response = restTemplate.getForObject("MY_ENDPOINT Response.class);
```

Here is my Response class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "info")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    private String version;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Response from server looks like this:

```
{
  "info": {
  "version":"3-SNAPSHOT",
  }
}
```

And this does not work because 'info' is not he root node of the response, I thought @JsonRootName(value="info") will treat "info" node as root node but it does not.

It would work if I would have a nother object and inside it I would have my Response object, but that seems like too much objects.

Comment: If you are getting object directly, why  do you need to go JSON way.  You don't even need to do JsonRootName and all. Simple get the object by restTemplate.exchange. It will be available in `ResponseEntity<Object_Name>`. get it's body. Your controller should be marked with `@ResponseBody` for return, and just simply return the POJO.

Comment: I'm calling an external API that returns me a JSON response. The response contains more nodes but i'm interested only in the 'info' node.

I'm not sure how your mentioned appproach would work, can you add a fe wlines of code to illustrate?

Comment: Sorry, if it's an external API(meaning you don't have control) over it, then don't know how to help. You posted the model like class, so I thought you can make changes in the server side project.